# Django session variables sometimes get lost in multi-threaded environment

Tags: django, multithreading, session, thread-safety, gevent

I'm trying to cache a set of strings per session by storing each one in their own variable and by using django.contrib.session.

I have the following code:

```
import copy

def get_result(request, operation):
    previous_result = request.session.get(operation.name)
    if previous_result:
        result = copy.deepcopy(previous_result)
    else:
        result = get_json_response(operation)
        request.session[operation.name] = copy.deepcopy(result)
    return result
```

get_result() is

1. triggered via ajax requests
2. used for many different operations which may be called at the same time
3. may be called multiple times per operation in one session

This code works perfectly fine on my local environment. However, in production server where gevent and chausette is installed, it fails.

Most of the time, request.session.get(operation.name) would return None even when it is not the first time that get_result is called for that operation. In some cases, it returns a value but in some, it doesn't. There seems to be no pattern on when it does and doesn't work.

I suspect that the inconsistency is because different threads are referencing the session variable at different states. What would be the proper way to handle session variables in this case?

Comment: Please show an example of some code that is calling this function, and also the implementation of `get_json_response`.

Comment: If you're using the `cache` session store with the `LocMemCache` backend, the session will be local to the process, which would explain the random behaviour. You can use memcached as a cache backend (so each process accesses the same cache), or switch to the `db`/`cached_db` session store.

Comment: @knbk I was using `db` session store with `LocMemCache`. Switching to `FileBasedCache` seems to have fixed the problem. What's the difference between `db` and `cached_db`? Don't they both use the same cache back-end anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I did in fact have the same problems and also tried to save the session properly with the tweaks you posted.

In the end, what solved my problem was changing the default cache in `settings.py` to

```py
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
```

Using `FileBasedCache` instead helps as well, but it crashes in the local environment (development). Dummy works for local as well as production.